Installing a 240V outlet on Aluminum Wiring for an Electric Oven in Old House
I would like to replace my gas stove with an electric stove. It seems like the kitchen was originally wired for an electric stove - there's a 50A breaker in the panel box labled "oven". I reached out for quotes from a couple of local electricians, and the rates seem extremely high for the work - $600 to install the outlet. Can someone here take a look and see if the price makes sense, or if I should try to do it myself?
The stove works with either a 10-50R or 14-50R outlet, but I think the 14-50R is the right choice.
I've swapped 120V outlets before, but this makes me a bit uncomfortable for three reasons:

The wiring is aluminum, not copper
The box shape is weird - I'm not sure if the box needs to be replaced.
The wires aren't properly marked. Ground is easy, but the other three wires look identical.

It sounds like some additional care is required to clean and coat the aluminum wires?
Here's the steps to install the outlet, from my understanding:

Shut off breaker
Clean Wires with Deoxit and wire brush
Apply Noalox to wire ends
Install outlet


Additional Info for the curious:
Electric Stove: LG LSIL6336FE
Manual: https://gscs-b2c.lge.com/downloadFile?fileId=bjQgwaTnNXzECjBHkKnuag
The outlets I am considering. I think the Bryant is probably overkill?
https://www.homedepot.com/p/Leviton-50-Amp-2-Pole-Flush-Mount-Shallow-Single-Outlet-Black-NEMA-6-50R-R10-05374-S00/300324220
https://www.zoro.com/zoro-select-receptacle-50-a-amps-125250v-ac-flush-mount-single-outlet-14-50r-black-9450fr/i/G4438388/
Noalox for coating the aluminum wires:
https://www.homedepot.com/p/Noalox-Anti-Oxidant-Compound-4-oz-30-026/202276208



NEMA 6 is hot, hot and ground.  Your stove probably requires a neutral.  NEMA 10 is hot, hot, and neutral(no ground), which is one reason it was ban in 96.  You have all the wires for NEMA 14 so no real question what to use.  You want a receptacle listed for aluminum usually cu/al.  With an inexpensive torque driver it will be safe.  The hots do not care which is which, the neutral should be white.

The electric stove in our 1970 build aluminum wired house was originally hard wired. The connection was in a loose metal box (not in the wall). It could be that this would be the simplest way to connect your new electric stove would be with Polaris connectors (with the grease in) . That box looks too small to fit a 14-50 receptacle rated for aluminum wiring. When I replaced the original electric range with another one I bought a 14-50R rated for aluminum at a big box store but I have never had any confidence in the quality of the connection with the stranded aluminum wire.

Will there be enough space behind the oven for a surface mounted box?

You didn't list the most important step of all: torque all connections (using an inch-pound screwdriver) to the torque specified by the manufacturer.

The biggest question is the size of the existing aluminum wires. You need 8 AWG for 40A, 6 AWG for 50A. Also need to make sure the receptacle is rated for aluminum - typically it will be an indication of CU/AL. Many are copper only.

The existing box looks like a metal 4-square box (Raco 8189) with a round mud ring (Raco 8756). You should be able to run you fingers inside the box and feel the corners. That round ring has exposed 8-32 screws hole with spacing intended for light fixtures rather than 6-32 that receptacles are made to mount to.
If you cut away the drywall you can replace the round mud ring with a rectangle 8779 or 8768 that you can fit a flush NEMA 14-50R as you have described (but that Zoro price is crazy). If you carefully trim the drywall and use an 8779 the trim cover (Leviton  R50-SL703-000) is larger than 4" and will cover the hole.
The only way to reliable identify the existing hot wires is with a volt meter.

Cross off the NEMA 10-50.  You cannot use it here since ground IS available.
I do not see you mentioning a torque screwdriver.  This is absolutely critical to the makeup of high power connections (in point of fact, low power connections too, as recent science revealed - also, experience does not improve ones ability to set torques by feel - testing was done at trade shows, and electricians weren't any more accurate than their companion/business manager/spouse.)
Noalox is not needed unless UL says it is, and if so they tend to require it to be pre-loaded in the terminal.
That receptacle opening is an odd duck.  It looks like they are using a 4x4 steel box with a "mud ring" of the octagon box style, used for light fixtures.  Or maybe I'm wrong - maybe some 14-50 sockets will screw into those holes?   Pretty sure it would NOT be the better Hubbell/BRyant type recommended for EV charging. But that is overkill here.
I would just avoid the notoriously bad Leviton.  The Legrand seems to enjoy a reputation of the least bad of the el-cheapo 14-50 range outlets.
The Leviton you linked is a 6-50 which contradicts your text.

I bought a Bryant 14-50R to replace the CU-AL 14-50R that I have no confidence in. Only when it arrived did I realize it is rated for copper conductor only! I then bought some Polaris connectors to pigtail, but I have not done the work yet. Probably will need a box extender.

@Jim Oh no!  I'm sorry to hear that.  Yeah, as far as AL accepting 14-50s, the Legrand is the least badly reviewed over on reddit r/evcharging.  As for the Hubbell/Bryant, many EVers would be happy to take it off your hands.  Just don't mention "hardwiring is better" :)
